# yii cdbcriteria->with child table record not displayed in view

Tags: php, yii

In yii based application  Im working on a search query. query is performed on two tables `customers` and `customerContacts`. Customer can have one-to-many contacts in different countries

Im using cdbcriteria as:

```
$criteria   = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->alias = 't' ;
$criteria->with= array("customerContacts"=> array("select"=>"customerContacts.fullname"));              
$criteria->condition = " customerContacts.country_id = 1";
$customers = Customer::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Relations are

In Costumer model:

```
'customerContacts' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'customerContacts', 'customer_id'),
```

in customerContact model:

```
'customer' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Customer', 'customer_id'),
```

Issue is that there is a fullname column in customerContact table. This cdbCriteria is picking that fullname but it is not displayed that in view page, although data exists in table.

view code

```
<?php foreach($customers as $customer):
    echo $customer->customerContacts->fullname;
endforeach; ?>
```

I'am stuck in this. please help where im doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using the "with" criteria?

Comment: for selecting records from both tables. from customers and customerContacts.

Comment: But that isn't necessary because you already create relations in the models. `with` is only needed if you want to use eager-loading. So, try skipping the 'with' part.

Comment: thanks. let me give it a try

Comment: with was used to load both table records at once that was requirement. If i remove with and try to run the code echo $customer->customerContacts->fullname; then i get  Trying to get property of non-object error.

Comment: Do you get any data from this query at all? is there anything in your log? And shouldn't the 'condition' be in the 'with' array, like this: `$criteria->with= array("customerContacts"=> array("select"=>"customerContacts.fullname","condition" => " customerContacts.country_id = 1"));`

Comment: yes im logingin the query and getting the data as well(When i use with). I get data from contacts as well but I dont know why it is not displaying. When i do print_r($customers) i get all data. When i run the query from log to phpmyadmin I get all data(both tables) but not able to show the contacts names in view.

Comment: And you do the `print_r($costumers)` in the view?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43816/discussion-between-veelen-and-maz-iqbal)

Answer (score 1):

First in your case it is not necessary to use the `with` in the condition, because you specified the relation, and customerContacts will be available using lazy-loading, and because you don;t need eager loading in this case, us can simply use

```
Customer::model()->findAll()
```

Secondly; You specify customerContacts relation as a HAS_MANY relation. The result of this is that `$customer->customerContacts` will be an array of objects.
So, in your view you'll have to use

```
<?php foreach($customers as $customer):
    foreach($customer->customerContact as $customerContact){
        echo $customerContacts->fullname;
    }
endforeach; ?>
```

But that is only appropriate if it is possible that an customer can have multiple customerContact records. 
If that ís possible, you will have to add a condition to your relation, because otherwise all customerRelation records will be shown. 
If thats not possible, you will have to change the relation to a HAS_ONE relation, and specify it's relating column.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Sorry I just updated. I am selecting fullname. that was a typo in posting

Comment: Does that also account for the typo in `echo $customer->customerContatcs->fullname;`?

Comment: Im  selecting the column fullname. array("select"=>"customerContacts.fullname")); and need to display it as echo $customer->customerContatcs->fullname;

Comment: I mean that there is an typo in your view file: `echo $customer->customerContatcs->fullname;` should be `echo $customer->customerContacts->fullname;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        <?php 
        $customers = Customer::model()->with('customerContacts')->findByPk(1); 
        echo $customers->name;
        foreach($customers->customerContacts as $contact)
        {
            echo $contact->fullname;
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Thanks answer. I cannot use findByPK because I need to select based on country.